# Insert statement with single quote for Integer datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have a table `table1` (`id` integer, `Name` varchar, `Age` integer)

While inserting rows into the table I use two statements.

1. `INSERT INTO TABLE1('1','John','33');`
   and
2. `INSERT INTO TABLE1(1,'John',33)`;

Both of them work fine. In the first `insert` statement I have used the value between single quote for the integer datatype as well.

Can I know what can be the difference between both of the statements?

Comment: The only difference is that the database has to convert the char '1' in first case to an integer.

Comment: And there's no reason at all to give integer values as character strings!

Comment: As Jens and jarlh wrote - the first one cause the database to implicitly convert your char value to an int value (and there really is no reason to do it), so it will make the server work a tiny bit harder. of course, where it's only one insert statement with one value set, it's impossible to feel the difference. However, when working on big, real time systems where there are a lot of insert statements per second (and by a lot I mean 10,000 and more), this may cause a noticeable difference.

Comment: Never rely on implicit data type conversion. Use the literal that is appropriate for the data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between using single quote for Integer datatype or not.

In first case it will load db server to convert your string literal to integer data type whereas in second case it will directly store integer value to database.

Its good to used without single quote,  since that would just be an extra unnecessary step for the database to convert the string literal into a numeric value and also make some little bit difference in performance when there are more records inserted at a time.